# What is the maximum value that cannot be attained from an unlimited number of coins worth 17, 21, 25, and 29 cents?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> I have an unlimited number of coins worth 17 cents, 21 cents, 25 cents, and 29 cents. What is the maximum number of cents that I cannot attain?

I know this is somewhat similar to the Chicken McNugget Theorem (Frobenius Coin Problem or Postage Stamp Problem). I tried using the fact that $ab-a-b$ but it is not too helpful with 4 numbers as it is pretty confusing and no theorem to it.
I also noticed each of these numbers is 4 apart which means that there would be some reason behind that. Apart from that, I also saw that all of the numbers are relatively prime so it would be a modification of the Chicken McNugget Problem.

Comment: FYI, since these values form an arithmetic sequence with the first value, $a = 17$, and the difference $d = 4$, being relatively prime, the formula given in the [Arithmetic sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem#Arithmetic_sequences) section of Wikipedia's "Coin problem" article gives you the answer.